# Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. ERROR 2332

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

In this project, my goal was to add data from local to the database using swagger, but I am encountering this error.

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. ERROR 2332

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>kodlamaio</groupId>
    <artifactId>hrms</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hrms</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-06-12 22:28:47.821 ERROR 2996 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass (org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass and org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at kodlamaio.hrms.HrmsApplication.main(HrmsApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass (org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass and org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.bind(PropertyBinder.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2299) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:979) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:806) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:248) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    ... 21 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm also adding the entity layer. Maybe the error comes from here.

entities:

```
package kodlamaio.hrms.entites.concretes;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "job_positions")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JobPosition {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
}
```

codes of another entity class:

```
package kodlamaio.hrms.entites.concretes;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "employers")
public class Employers extends User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue

    @Column(name = "company_name")
    private String companyName;

    @Column(name = "web_address")
    private String webAddress;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;
}
```

codes of another entity class:

```
package kodlamaio.hrms.entites.concretes;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "candidates")
public class Candidates extends User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "identity_number")
    private String identityNumber;

    @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
    private Date dateOfBirth;
}
```

codes of another entity class:

```
package kodlamaio.hrms.entites.concretes;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employees extends User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue

    @Column(name = "firs_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
}
```

codes of another entity class:

```
package kodlamaio.hrms.entites.concretes;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue

    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
}
```

Comment: It looks like a problem with Hibernate, possibly caused by your entities. Can you share their code please?

Comment: I added it to the question section. You can look there.

Comment: Is there only a single entity in your application? The error you are getting usually occurs when there are multiple entities and some sub-classing involved.

Comment: There are multiple entities, but I tried to do operations with the entity class I shared here. so i think i am getting error with this entity class. but I can still share other asset classes as well.

Comment: The error is occurring during startup when Hibernate processes all of your entities. It could be any of them that is causing the problem.

Comment: so what i do the error will be fixed

Comment: I added one more entity class. you can look

Comment: Could it be a database error? I think it is.

Comment: it seems like you have some parent-child relationship in your entities. Share the entities having a parent-child relationships in the quation.

Comment: I added all the entity classes. You can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by switching to [Springdoc](https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox). It can also generate Swagger UI page.